# How can I trim a huge text file?

Tags: logging, trim, irc

So I've been using [Willie](http://willie.dftba.net/) for about 8 months now, and it records a raw.log of everything that goes on in the IRC channel it runs in. Now, the issue with that is it records a LOT of unnecessary, well, bloat.

Here's an example:

```
<<1419986827.01 :BotSelig!willie@Snoonet-bhs.ien.kdgglt.IP NICK Snoo62763
>>1419986827.04 PRIVMSG Snoo62763 :TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting (file "C:\Python27\willie\willie\coretasks.py", line 254, in track_nicks)
<<1419986827.12 :Snoo62763!willie@Snoonet-bhs.ien.kdgglt.IP PRIVMSG Snoo62763 :TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting (file "C:\Python27\willie\willie\coretasks.py", line 254, in track_nicks)
<<1419986827.22 :NickServ!NickServ@services.snoonet.org NOTICE Snoo62763 :Welcome to Snoonet, Snoo62763! Here on Snoonet, we provide services to enable the registration of nicknames and channels! For details, type /msg NickServ help and /msg ChanServ help.
<<1419986832.84 :venn177!venn177@user/venn177 PRIVMSG #RLB :uh, well, this seems to work
<<1419986832.84 :venn177!venn177@user/venn177 PRIVMSG #RLB :in any case, let's try this
>>1419986852.92 QUIT :KeyboardInterrupt
>>1419986861.61 CAP LS
>>1419986861.61 NICK BotSelig
>>1419986861.62 USER willie +iw BotSelig :Willie Embosbot, http://willie.dftba.net
<<1419986861.67 :veronica.snoonet.org NOTICE Auth :*** Looking up your hostname...
```

So out of all of that, the only thing I'd want to keep is the text that takes place after the "#RLB :". I'd like to keep each line of 'text' on its own line still, but trim out all of that unnecessary fluff. So how could I have something read each line of a text file, check if it has "#RLB :" in it, and then only save everything that takes place after that?

The end goal is to have what amounts to a database for generating markov chains, which obviously won't work with all of that bloat there. (I don't actually know if it helps knowing that)

I guess another way of stating it is that I'd like to take what's stated up there, and just trim it down to this:

```
uh, well, this seems to work
in any case, let's try this
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's a Perl solution:

```
perl -i -ne 'print if s/^.*?#RLB ://' log.txt
```

(I'm assuming a unixish shell. In Windows single quotes won't work and you'll have to use double quotes instead: `-ne "..."`)

`-i` means it modifies the file in place.
`-n` runs the provided code for each line.
`-e ...` specifies the code right on the command line.

The code itself uses a regex-based search/replace instruction. We're looking for

```
^       # beginning of line
.*?     # anything (any character, 0 or more times, as few as possible)
#RLB :  # the text "#RLB :"
```

and replacing it by nothing, thus removing it. This leaves only the text after it.

We only output lines that were successfully modified. This effectively filters out all other lines, leaving the messages.